# OleDbDataAdapter Update question

Tags: c#, oledb

I have a DataTable with a lot of rows (Over a hundred million) and am writing an application that needs to insert into that table.

I will be using OleDbDataAdapter for the job and I am puzzled whats the best way to do this. I only need to insert into this enormous table, however I don't want to hard code the insert statement into application.

I figured I could use

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from table_name");
OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
...
adapter.Fill(data_set_name, "Table_name");
```

But this would be really **bad** since I don't need/want the data and the memory usage would be awful. So I was interesting if I could alter SelectCommand with TOP? It would look like so:

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select TOP 1 * from table_name");
```

Now the Fill command would be really fast and I would have the data I needed for all the future insert statements. I could add rows to datatable and then just call

```
adapter.Update(data_set_name, "Table_name");
```

Would this work? And is this a valid / recommended way of doing this? It is really important that the application is fast and uses only the necessary resources. Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the data you can change the select command to

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE 1=2
```

Then you won't get any rows back

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the best way would be to:

1. Use the `OleDbDataAdapter.FillSchema(data_set_name, SchemaType.Source)` method to create the DataTable with a structure mapped from the datasource. You are basically trying to do the same thing by pulling a single row in your Select statement. Your Select statement in this case could remain "`select * from table_name`". I believe that you do not need to call the `OleDbDataAdapter.Fill` method now.
2. Instead of using a `CommandBuilder`, create your `InsertCommand` statement yourself.

Comment: Well I'm sure this would work, but it's not really helpful since I don't want to write the InsertCommand statement myself. Also I would like to call the fill method, since then I could use a DataSet to Update the table. If there is something I'm missing please let me know.