# OleDbException in my update method

Tags: c#, oledb

Why do I have this error? The error message is: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

I want to add a record to my database, but it isn't working. Where is the problem?

The code is:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter DbDataAdabter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DbDataAdabter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Phone-Book]", connection);

        OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(DbDataAdabter);
        connection.Open();
        DataRow dataRow = myDataset.Tables["salam"].NewRow();

        dataRow[1] = textBox2.Text;
        dataRow[2] = textBox3.Text;
        dataRow[3] = textBox4.Text;
        dataRow[4] = textBox5.Text;

        dataRow.EndEdit();
        myDataset.Tables["salam"].Rows.Add(dataRow);

        DbDataAdabter.Update(myDataset , "salam");

        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Start at dataRow[0] and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant: dataRow[0] is auto numbber !

Comment: I don't think the code you have posted tells the whole story. Can you post the complete stacktrace? Also when you use the using statement in c#, the object will be disposed so remove the connection.Dispose() line in your code.

Comment: Where's do you set the `DbDataAdabter.InsertCommand`?

Comment: @SimonWilson : how should i set that ?

Comment: @HamedNorouzi - Read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594063/oledbdataadapter-update-question?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The error is with the code generated by the Update() method, given the metadata inherent in the query for the information and the results. It would help if you gave us the SqlString property of the exception so we can see what's being sent to Sql Server.

I will tell you that the problem with your code that jumped out at me first off is the use of `Select *`. Pretty much any query that uses a `*` that isn't a `Count(*)` is not a query you should use in production code; they have their uses in one-off queries executed from Management Studio, but not in queries that are consumed by programs or by other queries.

In this case, `SELECT *` allows you no control over the number of columns your query produces; if someone comes in later and adds a column, all of a sudden your application starts behaving badly because you only wanted 3 columns, not 4. Use a property list on any SELECT statement executed from code.

Comment: I'm learning C#.net and database from this site http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p10.html
and it learned me this code ! i don't understand what's your meaning!?

Comment: He's asking you to post the full exception so we can see the actual SQL query that your code is attempting to execute on the database. If you're learning c# why don't you try and learn Linq and use Entity Framework?